# Can I Implement Identity Server 4 to Be An OIDC Identity Provider ONLY?

Tags: identityserver4

I've got an odd legacy situation which I won't bore you with, but the long and the short of it is I need to create the functionality in my web application so that it can act as an identity provider - not a authorization token service. We've already got an STS, I just need to integrate with it and play the role of an external identity provider. We're using OIDC Authorization Code flow + PKCE.

Can Identity Server be configured this way? Are there any examples of this? Almost every example I've seen is identity server serving as the token provider, and also as an IdP many times, but never *just* as an IdP. Does that exist? Can it?

Thanks!

Andy

Comment: If you don't define any API resources then it would do what you describe. How would you define the difference?

Comment: My understanding is there are 2 distinct functionalities, one is that of the authentication authority (IdP) which handles the actual login and identifies the user. The other is the authorization authority which hands out authorization tokens (STS) which have claims that designate the permissions a user or client has for a given resource. Identity Server can certainly function as the STS without being the IdP, but I've never seen an example of the reverse.

So, do I just configure the STS as a client, and just ignore resources?

Comment: Yes - OIDC can serve purely as an IDP and not provide access to any resources other than itself. The protocol doesn't differ at all in this case, you just end up with an access token that can only call the IDP userinfo endpoint.